# Is there a way to find the databricks notebook which contain the Create table logic of hive_metastore tables

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks

Is there a way to find the databricks notebook which contain the create logic if I know the Hive_metastore DB/tables name.

I want to understand the logic and the reason I am trying to backtrack from table but the person who has create the table is not around.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know in which notebook create logic is stored, go to:

**Data >> Click on the table**

[image]

then **Click on History** here you will find **`Cluster id`** and **`Notebook id`** in which table is created.

[image]

from this information you can identify notebook and find the logic of table.